# Collector for the fastest minor gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the "Fundamentals of JVM tuning" talk by Charlie Hunt
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4joWshvFJnw&noredirect=1

The slide at 10:06 asserts that: "Parallel GC offers the fastest minor GC times". However the talk doesnt explain why this is.

It might be obvious, but nonetheless I would appreciate any reasoning/proof backing up the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

While the serial GC uses only one thread to process a GC, the parallel GC uses several threads to process a GC, and therefore, faster. This GC is useful when there is enough memory and a large number of cores.

[refer to this link for explaination](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/)

Comment: The parallel GC also has the benefit of reducing the number to stop the world GC events because it can usually keep up with your allocations/deallocations of objects.

Comment: What do you mean by enough memory ? Which Memory area exactly you are talking about for minor gc ?

Comment: @Batty: both CMS and parallel use multiple threads to process a GC in eden. (ParNew for CMS and Parallel Scavenge for Parallel)